# Laravel 4 - Bootstrap glyphicons

Tags: view, laravel-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

Does anybody know how can I do to put a `Bootstrap glyphicon` in my

`{{ link_to_route('post.create', 'New' ) }}`

I would like to show a glyphicon just before 'New', and I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
<a href="{{ route('post.create') }}">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
        <span>New</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a helper like this one:

```
function icon_link_to_route($icon, $route, $title = null, $parameters = array(), $attributes = array())
{
    $url = route($route, $parameters);

    $title = (is_null($title)) ? $url : e($title);

    $attributes = HTML::attributes($attributes);

    $title = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-'.e($icon).'"></span>' . $title;

    return '<a href="'.$url.'"'.$attributes.'>'.$title.'</a>';
}
```